# Javascript setAttribute is not working to update attribute's value

Tags: javascript, callback, setattribute

This is my code.

```
var hitButton = document.querySelector('.btn-hit');
var scoreResults = document.querySelectorAll(".flex-blackjack-row-1 h3");
var scores = document.querySelector(".flex-blackjack-row-1 span");

const config = {childList: true};

const bustedMessage = document.createElement('h2');
bustedMessage.textContent = 'BUSTED!';

const busted = function (mutationList, observer){
    if (parseInt(scores.textContent) > 21) {
        console.log(scores.textContent)
        scoreResults[0].before(bustedMessage);
        hitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
    }
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(busted);
observer.observe(scores, config);
```

In that callback function named "busted", I'm **adding** an attribute to "hitButton". But when I try to update it like this in another function

```
hitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'false');
```

it is not being updated.

But I can remove that attribute using

```
hitButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Removing that attribute is doing what I want to do. But now I need to know, why can not I update it instead of removing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, these attributes in HTML tags are just boolean attributes. Say for e.g., if "disabled" attribute is present, it tells the browser to disable it regardless of the value you are setting to it.

"checked", "disabled", "selected", "muted", "autoplay", "loop", "controls" are some of the boolean attributes in HTML.

Google "Boolean attributes in HTML". You will learn more about it. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: This is what I got after googling it. It explains everything, Thanks for your guidence.
"A Boolean attribute is an attribute that can only be true or false. How does a Boolean attribute work? According to the HTML specification: The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the “true” value, and the absence of the attribute represents the “false” value."